# second order ode $u''(x)=k^2u(x)$, $u(\pi)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Would appreciate if someone would solve explicitly the following second order ode:

$u''(x)=k^2u(x)$

$u(\pi)=0$.

I know the result is supposed to be $u(x)=c_k\sinh(k(x-\pi))$

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried already to solve this problem? Do you know how to solve a general constant coefficient second order ode?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $$u(x)=e^{\lambda x}$$
then you will get
$$\lambda^2-k^2=0$$ so we get
$$(k-\lambda)(k+\lambda)=0$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

$$u''(x)=k^2u(x) \to R^2-k^2=0 \to R=\mp k$$
The general solution is
$$u(x)=K_1e^{kx}+K_2e^{-kx}$$
Since $u(\pi)=0$
$$K_1e^{k\pi}+K_2e^{-k\pi}=0 \to K_2=-K_1e^{2k\pi}$$
Therefore :
$$u=K_1(e^{kx}-e^{2k\pi-kx})$$
$$u=\underbrace{2K_1e^{k\pi}}_{\text {constante K}}\left (\frac {e^{k(x-\pi)}-e^{-k(x-\pi)}} 2 \right)$$
$$\boxed{u(x)=K\sinh(k(x-\pi))}$$